# WPF Window Not Visible

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created a WPF Application.  When this application is launched with a command line argument, In App.xaml.cs, I set a boolean variable to true. It then shows a notification icon in the system tray and creates an object of MainWindow class and calls `ShowDialog()` on it

The main window contructor is as follows:

```
public MainWindow(){
   InitializeComponent();

   if (GlobalVariables.bLaunchedInNotificationMode){
      this.ShowInTaskbar = false;
      this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Minimized;
      this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Hidden;
      NotifyIconHelper.GetInstance().NotifyIconContextMenuClick+= new NotifyIconContextMenuHandler(ChangeMainWindowVisibility);
   }
}
```

That means if it called with argument, app.xaml.cs sets the variable `bLaunchedInNotificationMode` to true.
After setting the variable to true, I show the notification balloon in system tray.
After the code for displaying the notification balloon, In App.xaml.cs i write:

```
MainWindow objMainWindow = new MainWindow();
objMainWindow.ShowDialog();
```

This calls the contructor above and main window is launched in hidden.
I also have a context menu item on notification balloon, which says Launch App, On click of this context menu, In MainWindow I do:

```
this.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
this.ShowInTaskbar = true;
this.WindowState = System.Windows.WindowState.Normal;
```

During debugging, I verified that this keyword represents MainWindow but even after setting all three properties, the window does not show up. What is wrong here ?

Comment: Why are you calling `ShwoDialog` instead of the usual `Show`?

Comment: Show() should help you. @Clemens is right.

Comment: I tried changeing it to Show(), still it does not work

Comment: are u sure enough that you are not getting any error and your above code runs without error ?

Comment: Can you post your App.xaml.cs code? What you are describing sounds like you changed the code in the way that you called ShowDialog before app.Run() is called. If that is the case, windows messages will not be processed and UI will not be responsive (because code will wait on ShowDialog before continuing and in app.Run WPF application really sets up by creating Dispatcher object, starting message pump to process windows messages etc). It would be helpful if you post App.xaml.cs code.